# Migrating Salesforce data to Heroku Postgres

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

I am using 'Heroku Connect' as the connector for Integrating Salesforce and Heroku post-gres.

By using Heroku connect,
When I create a record in Salesforce, it automatically created in Heroku but unfortunately the same thing happen for deletetion.

I want to migrate the records from salesforce to heroku for that I need only insert action. And also I want to migrate the records which should be 3 months prior to created date.

Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Connect does not support synching a subset of data ([reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect-faq#can-i-synchronize-a-subset-of-data-from-salesforce)). You could use an integration user who has limited access to record set in theory, but that may not work in your case if you do not want to sync deletes.

You could create a custom solution based on keys/logged date to extract data from Salesforce and import in Postgres. Explore backup / other sync options like Skyvia, OwnBackup, Backupify etc. if you do not want to hand code the solution.